# Julia Flux.Dense initial conditions

Tags: neural-network, julia

I can’t figure out the syntax to initialize the weights for Flux.Dense.

```
using Flux 
w0 = Float32[1, 2, 3, 4] 
nn = Dense(4, 1, relu; initW = w0)
```

produces the following error.

```
MethodError: objects of type Array{Float32,2} are not callable
```

so it seems the initW needs to be a function of some kind.

I also tried

```
nn = Dense(4, 1, relu)
nn.W = w0
```

and got error

```
setfield! immutable struct of type Dense cannot be changed
```

which seems to be saying I can’t change the Dense object (?).

Thanks for looking!

(Julia 1.4.2 and Flux v0.11.0)

Answer (score 1):

initW parameter is not the weight vector, it is for change the function that init the weights. You can put a function or try

```
nn = Dense(4, 1, relu)
nn.W .= w0
```

The operator .= update the values.

Unfortunately I have not access to my computer to check it.

Comment: Thanks! The .= construct worked, and I could redefine the initial conditions. However, I tried setting w0 as a function ("function w0(); return Float32[1, 2, 3, 4]; end") run with "nn = Dense(4, 1, relu; initW = w0)" and got an error that "no method matching w0(::Int64, ::Int64)". Where can I find more information about correctly setting the function that initialized the weights?